# How to add a required checkbox to checkout page (policy check)

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, xml, checkbox

I know that there is basic functionality, but it does not suit me.

How to display my template under the form with the link to the privacy-policy page?

Or tell me how to do it right. I need a checkbox under the form that asks to confirm that the privacy policy has been read.

I create a js file: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/checkout-privacy.js`

```
define(
    ['ko', 'uiComponent'],
    function (ko, Component) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/checkout-privacy/checkout-privacy'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

and file: app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/checkout-privacy/checkout-privacy.html

```
<form id="checkbox-policy-form" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-policy input required-entry" data-validate="{ required: true, 'validate-one-required-by-name': true, attr: { id: 'checkbox-policy' }}">
    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {for: 'checkbox-policy'}">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'I agree to the'"></span>
        <a href="checkbox-policy" data-bind="i18n: 'Terms and Conditions'"></a>
    </label>
</form>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkbox-policy-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

on payment step

Comment: Terms and Conditions you are enable in admin panel ???

Comment: @MohitPatel 
This functionality does not suit me, it calls popup with text, but I need something without a mandatory checkbox in which part of the text is a link to the "privacy-policy" page. Like - `<span data-bind="i18n: 'I agree to the'"></span><a href="checkbox-policy" data-bind="i18n: 'Terms and Conditions'"></a>`

Comment: check this link --- https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-magento-2-terms-and-conditions-checkbox/

Comment: @MohitPatel I don't need popup, this method is not for me, I know how to turn it on but it doesn’t suit me

Answer (score 0):

check ur layout

use this one as an example

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="beforeMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="privacy-policy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-privacy</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to do this as part of the form and check when submit? At the moment, the component displays under payment methods